# What is postgresql equivalent of OBJECT_ID() in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to translate a SQL Server stored procedure to Postgresql. I did it except that part:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrdersToDistribute') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #OrdersToDistribute
```

because I don't know what is Postgresql equivalent of `OBJECT_ID()` function in SQL Server? Does anyone know is there such a function in Postgres at all?

I was searching in postgresql documentation but did not find `OBJECT_ID()` function.

Comment: You don't need that: `drop table if exists OrdersToDistribute;` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should rethink your temporary table usage. In most of the cases you probably don't need a temp table to begin with in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you, "drop table if exists OrdersToDistribute" did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The DROP TABLE docs for Postgres should get you what you want, including dropping a table that exists:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbPasos;
```